# On Ruby on Rails, how do we print debug info inside of a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

In PHP, CGI, or in RoR's View, we can easily print out debug information.  How about in the Controller, how can we just say, `print "hello world"` (to the webpage output) and return to continue with the view, or stop the controller right there?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

In the controller you can:

```
render :text => @some_object.inspect
```

But your view won't be rendered.

You could also:

```
Rails.logger.debug("My object: #{@some_object.inspect}")
```

and run tail on log/development.log to see the output.

In the view the recommeneded way is:

```
<%= debug(@some_object) %>
```

Comment: This is well [documented here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger).

Comment: I have put <%= debug(@some_object) %> for my instance object in view. But its getting printed as it is without showing me the value of object.

Comment: debug() tries to call to_yaml() on the object. If it can't, it calls inspect() instead.

Comment: That's too bad that there is nothing similar to Symfony's VarDumper package http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html , it shows whole object, and each propertly and subproperty in beatiful expanding tree.

Comment: For controller better stop app also: `abort(@some_object.inspect)`

Answer (score 5):

Don't know about `print`, but `puts` never failed me. Your `hello world` will be in console and logs and normal flow will continue.
Did I understand you correctly?

Answer (score 5):

You can debug in the view: `<%= debug @post %>`. More info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Answer (score 3):

you can use abort with inspect

```
abort params[:whatevs].inspect
```

or

```
abort @my_variable.inspect
```

for **JSON** format

```
render json: JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(@my_variable.to_json))
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Nikita's suggestion isn't bad.  But usually it is hard to look at the data in the terminal because the screen buffer size can be limited and it is full of previous data from previous rendering of pages.

But, say on the Mac, just make sure the screen buffer is large enough, and also use in the `rails server` terminal the key <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> to clear the whole screen buffer first, and use the browser to fetch a webpage, and now use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> to search for the string you printed out, and it works quite well also.  Actually if <kbd>Cmd</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> is used to first clear the whole screen buffer, then the print out should always fit in the screen buffer.

Update: With Rails 3.x, we can make use of `flash.error`, `flash.notice`, `flash.now.notice` to print out something in the view if we want to: https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/11/rails-flash-messages/

Example:

```
flash.notice = "DEBUG INFO: some_obj is #{some_obj.inspect}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller:

```
 render json: @some_object
 return
```

It will show the object as JSON directly in the browser and stop execution. You can use some browser extensions like *JSONView* for Chrome to prettify the JSON in the browser.

[image]